# ng-repeat in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a custom select directive with some extra functionality.

```
.directive('singleSelect',function(){
restrict:'A'
scope:{
model:'='
}
link:function(elem,scope,attrs){
elem.bind('click',function(){
scope.vModel=model.slice(0,20);
});
controller:function($scope)
{
//some more manipulation with model and assign to vModel 
}
template:'<ul><li ng-repeat="item in vModel"></li><ul>'
});
```

The problem is that I am assigning the value to vModel but it is not getting updated in the template.

Comment: The answers are right about `$apply` but the code you posted is full of other problems too. Syntax errors like `function(){ restrict: 'A'`, there is not much to click in empty '<ul>' element, parameters `elem` and `scope` are in the wrong order in the `link` function and in the end, when this finally works, it will just show bunch of bullets (if even that, depends on your css) because there is nothing inside the '<li>'.

Comment: Sorry My mistake. Actually it is E. Also parameter order is wrong. Thanks all for the answer. I have updated my code and it is working fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are updating your scope variable inside a jQuery selector. You need to use $scope.$apply to start the digest cycle which will update your model.

Try this:

```
.directive('singleSelect',function(){
restrict:'A'
scope:{
model:'='
}
link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
elem.bind('click',function(){
scope.$apply(function(){
   scope.vModel=model.slice(0,20);
})
});
controller:function($scope)
{
//some more manipulation with model and assign to vModel 
}
template:'<ul><li ng-repeat="item in vModel"></li><ul>'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, that arguments in link function go in order just like below:
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs)

Try to use $apply method:

```
elem.bind('click',function(){
 scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.vModel=model.slice(0,20);
      }); 
});
```

And the best way to catch click event is use angular ng-click directive:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick